# How to efficiently animate a Graphviz graph?

Tags: python, animation, graph, graphviz

I would like to animate a Graphviz generated graph, changing the node labels and the node and edge colors.

I was creating the graphs using this [Python interface for Graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz). The only way to do that seems to be to create every image independently (although the changes between frames would be very small) and join all the images into an animation, as explained [here](http://gromgull.net/blog/2011/02/creating-animations-with-graphviz/).

Is there a more efficient way to create the animation, avoiding the creation of all these images independently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [python package (GraphvizAnim)](https://github.com/mapio/GraphvizAnim) to do so.
Being in alpha only, but non the less looking quite decent.

Answer (score 12):

There is also [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz), which takes a full dot graph description per animation step, converts it into an SVG, and then uses JavaScript to convert one graph into the other, and to inject  animation.

You can see an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/magjac/4acffdb3afbc4f71b448a210b5060bca).